# How To get The Total of values in Flutter firestore? elevated button text

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

so below iam able to get the total sum of my prices from firestore but i cant seem to be able to call it to text in elevated button here is my code the total sum comes to me correct as i said but the thing is calling the final value to my button any help will be appreciated

```
class cartpage extends StatefulWidget {
  const cartpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<cartpage> createState() => _cartpageState();
}

class _cartpageState extends State<cartpage> {

  AuthService get _auth => AuthService();
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> Cart = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Cart')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("UserCart")
      .doc('test')
      .collection('final')
      .snapshots();
  var total = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Cart')
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .collection("UserCart")
      .doc('test')
      .collection('final')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) {
    num sum = 0.0;
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
      num value = element.data()["Price"];
      sum = sum + value;
    });
   
    return sum;
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  // i removed some of the code from here //
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('$sum'),
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Update this is my current code i get the sum and it shows in the button but as i mentioned when on this cart page and want to remove something from cart the changes doesnt apply.

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Cart')
                .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                .collection("UserCart")
                .doc('test')
                .collection('final')
                .get(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> QuerySnapshot) {
              if (QuerySnapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Something went wrong");
              }

              if (QuerySnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                QuerySnapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
                  sumtotal = sumtotal +
                      doc["Price"]; // make sure you create the variable sumTotal somewhere
                });
                return ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: null,
                    child: Text('Submit total price RM ${sumtotal}'));
              }

              return Text("loading");
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Firebase request returns you some data correctly, but you should remember that it takes some time. In your example you are trying to use `sum` variable, but this variable does not receive the data form Firebase. You should first display some Loading (e.q.: `CircularProgressIndicator` widget) and call a Firebase request. When you receive the response, then you can change the state and pass `sum` to your widget.
So create asynchronous method and move your Firebase request call there with `await` keyword.
PS. So you use some state management? e.g: BLoC?

Comment: ok thanks i know what was my error thanks very much

Comment: Good, so could you please 'mark this answer as useful'? Thank you.

Comment: only ne small probem iam facing iam gettin everything and all but if i delete from my cart page the object  the sumtotal stays the same it doesnt update how can i fix that it does update when i leave to the main page and come back but i want it to automatically update without leaving the cart page